# How do I replace an item in array with another item in a different array?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, replace

I know the basic way of replacing an item in a string, but now how I am doing it. Here's my code. I'm trying to search a note for certain words and swap them out when I do find them. I have certain words to replace other certain words with and I need to match them up so the sentence still makes sense.

```
func searchNote1()
{
    let contentArr = note1.content.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    let count = contentArr.count
    var num = 0
    while num < count
    {
        if conciseArr.contains(contentArr[num])
        {
            contentArr[num] = conciseArr []
        }
        num += 1
    }
}
```

I am trying to replace the string in contentArr[num]  (wherever a certain word is found) and swap it out with the string found in conciseArr. Where I am stuck is how do I know the location of the word in conciseArr to replace the other word with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than .contains, look at indexOfObject.
If the object exists in the conciseArray, you will get the index (location), otherwise you will get an NSNotFound.
Then, if (location != NSNotFound)... (do your swap using the known indices)

And, while we're at it, perhaps fast enumeration would be appropriate here?
(I'm an Obj-C guy; I hope my Swift syntax is right!)

```
func searchNote1()
{
    let contentArr = note1.content.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    for (index, element) in contentArr.enumerate()
    {
        var location = conciseArr.indexOfObject(element)
        if (location != NSNotFound)
        {
            contentArr[index] = conciseArr[location]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, temporarily. Now when the function has to replace more than one word in a sentence it just becomes one big jumble. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I would need to see the input and output to understand what is happening.

Comment: Is there a way to PM on here or something? I don't want to post another question if I don't have to.

Comment: @SethRodgers I don't think there is a PM. You don't need to post another question, just put in some sample data and your result here, and I'll fix my answer to address your problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Given a sentence and a dictionary of synonyms

```
let sentence = "What a wonderful world"
let synonyms = ["wonderful":"beautiful", "world":"planet"]
```

### This is how you get a new sentence with the synonyms

```
let newSentence = sentence
    .componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    .map { synonyms[$0] ?? $0 }
    .joinWithSeparator(" ")
```

### That's it

```
print(newSentence) // What a beautiful planet
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out:

```
if conciseArr.contains(contentArr[num])
        {
            contentArr[num] = conciseArr.indexOf(contentArr[num])
        }
```